# Stencil Theme set up Fails on init

Tags: bigcommerce

Ok so i have run through all the data for getting a stencil theme to run. So far everything was ok then I tried to do stencil init and get an error.

```
My-iMac:stencil my$ stencil init
? What is the URL of your store's home page? example.com
? What port would you like to run the server on? 3000
? What is your Stencil Username? admin
? What is your Stencil Token? My Token
JavaScript Bundling Started...
Potentially unhandled rejection [6] Error: Error loading "github:davatron5000/FitVids.js@1.1.0/jquery.fitvids.js" at file:/Users/my/Documents/CentricSites/mydomain/stencil/assets/jspm_packages/github/davatron5000/FitVids.js@1.1.0/jquery.fitvids.js.js
Error loading "github:davatron5000/FitVids.js@1.1.0/jquery.fitvids.js" from "js/app" at file:/Users/my/Documents/CentricSites/mydomain/stencil/assets/js/app.js
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/my/Documents/CentricSites/mydomain/stencil/assets/jspm_packages/github/davatron5000/FitVids.js@1.1.0/jquery.fitvids.js.js'
at Error (native)
my-iMac:stencil my$
```

As you can see it is putting an extra file type extension .
jquery.fitvids.js this file exists but it seems to be looking for .js.js

I ran into the on another file and added an additional .js to the file name and that error went away, however, there are so many files I do not want to rename all of them. I have reached out to PixelUnion from where we got the Stencil theme from and they said that I had to come back to BigCommerce. I am hoping you can help me.

Comment: Actually I did find the answer to this one.  in the .js files it is trying to add an extra extension in the stencil theme.  I had to edit each file to remove the extra .js In this particular instance the file was this:
module.exports = require("github:davatron5000/FitVids.js@1.1.0/jquery.fitvids.js");
I just removed the .js from this file and many others and this part no longer threw errors. I am still having many other issues though.

Answer (score 1):

Back Up before Reinstalling
If you are reinstalling over a base theme on which you have already begun development, first back up at least your theme's .stencil file. This file contains your store URL, your  themes username and access tokens, and other basic settings. Preserving those settings will speed up initializing and launching the new version.

To allow complete rollback, back up your whole  directory. (In a default installation, this directory is named (stencil)

Comment: Ok so i have uninstalled and reinstalled like 3 times and am till getting an error where when running it is looking for js files with a .js.js extension.